# CMake: What is the modern syntax for target_link_libraries + LINK_PUBLIC

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I have plenty of this CMake syntax in my project:

```
target_link_libraries(<target>
                      <LINK_PRIVATE|LINK_PUBLIC> <lib>...
                     [<LINK_PRIVATE|LINK_PUBLIC> <lib>...]...)
```

And I read in their [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#libraries-for-a-target-and-or-its-dependents-legacy), that it is Legacy (say deprecated) since the policy [CMP0022](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0022.html#policy:CMP0022).

However, I'm not able to find the replacement syntax.

I just understood it should be something impacting `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` and `LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: `LINK_PRIVATE` and `LINK_PUBLIC` should be replaced with `PRIVATE` or `PUBLIC`. It says so right there in the link you provided.

Comment: Or `INTERFACE`, provided I move my link instruction on the sub-level which is a static lib in my case, which implies the dependency. Thank you @super .
(tlnr: `PUBLIC` = `INTERFACE` + `PRIVATE` )